# OrderedDictionary is not being saved when saving Settings

Tags: c#, winforms, appsettings

In my application I've implemented a few `Controls` to browse data in different ways. In every Control I display a `TreeView` to allow the user to go from a folder to another.

I would like my Controls to "remember" the last selected tree, in a generic way (I mean that if, in the future I add another Control I don't want to do a lot of adaptations). So I added an `OrderedDictionary` in the Settings. I use the Control's Type Name as a key and the Node's path as value.

As I was unable to set a default value for this dictionary I used this trick:

Settings.cs :

```
public OrderedDictionary Paths
{
    get
    {
        return LastsPaths ?? (LastsPaths = new OrderedDictionary());
    }
    set
    {
        this["LastsPaths"] = value;
    }
}
```

Settings.Designer.cs:

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public global::System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary LastsPaths {
    get {
        return ((global::System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary)(this["LastsPaths"]));
    }
    set {
        this["LastsPaths"] = value;
    }
}
```

I do call `Save` each time I add/update a value, the `user.config` file timestamps change, but the content stays the same:

```
<setting name="LastsPaths" serializeAs="Xml">
    <value />
</setting>
```

It doesn't work with:

- App in debug mode;
- App in release mode;
- App installed.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `OrderedDictionary` (and generic dictionaries in general) [are not XML serializable](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9bc9c0b3-7995-4e8e-b2be-179fdbf29bcb/is-it-possible-to-use-systemcollectionsspecializedordereddictionary-type-in?forum=vbgeneral).

You can wrap it in another class that does the serialization manually. In that way you don't expose the dictionary directly to the XML serializer. You have to implement [`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This might be enough to get you started. This inherits `IXMLSerializable` which is needed during the Save call.

```
[XmlRoot("PreviouslyVisitedPaths")]
public class PreviouslySelectedPaths : OrderedDictionary, IXmlSerializable
{

    #region Implementation of IXmlSerializable

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is reserved and should not be used. When implementing the IXmlSerializable interface, you should return null (Nothing in Visual Basic) from this method, and instead, if specifying a custom schema is required, apply the <see cref="T:System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaProviderAttribute"/> to the class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// An <see cref="T:System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema"/> that describes the XML representation of the object that is produced by the <see cref="M:System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter)"/> method and consumed by the <see cref="M:System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader)"/> method.
    /// </returns>
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates an object from its XML representation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader">The <see cref="T:System.Xml.XmlReader"/> stream from which the object is deserialized. </param>
    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        var keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(object));
        var valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(object));

        var wasEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;
        reader.Read();

        if(wasEmpty)
        {
            return;
        }

        while(reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            reader.ReadStartElement("item");

            reader.ReadStartElement("key");
            var key = keySerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.ReadEndElement();

            reader.ReadStartElement("value");
            var value = valueSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.ReadEndElement();

            Add(key, value);

            reader.ReadEndElement();
            reader.MoveToContent();
        }
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an object into its XML representation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">The <see cref="T:System.Xml.XmlWriter"/> stream to which the object is serialized. </param>
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        var keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(object));
        var valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(object));

        foreach(var key in Keys)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("item");

            writer.WriteStartElement("key");
            keySerializer.Serialize(writer, key);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement("value");
            var value = this[key];
            valueSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

You would then change your code to this:

```
public PreviouslySelectedPaths Paths
{
    get
    {
        return LastsPaths ?? (LastsPaths = new PreviouslySelectedPaths());
    }
    set
    {
        this["LastsPaths"] = value;
    }
}
```

You would also need to make `LastsPaths` type `PreviouslySelectedPaths`.

This is just to get your started you may need to tweek the `IXMLSerializable` methods and fill in logic for `GetSchema()`.